# How to get param value in to arg in roslaunch?

Tags: ros, rosparam, roslauch, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ros kinetic
I have ros parameter name "tal"

I want to get this param value into argument tag.

```
<arg name="tal_arg" value=??? />
```

I am using ros kinetic,
this [post](https://answers.ros.org/question/234510/get-run_id-param-into-an-arg-with-roslaunch/) suggest to use eval, but I don't know how to do it.
Can you help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/310093/how-to-get-param-value-in-to-arg-in-roslaunch?/) by [Tal](https://answers.ros.org/users/11486/tal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2018-12-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pmuthu2s](https://answers.ros.org/users/33024/pmuthu2s/) on 2018-12-06**:
Did you try putting the value in double quotes?

Like this,

```
<arg name="foo" value="bar" />
```

as given in the [link](https://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/arg)

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-12-06**:
I think the OP is asking how to put a dynamic parameter value into an argument not a literal value.

**Comment by [Tal](https://answers.ros.org/users/11486/tal/) on 2018-12-06**:
I want to put the value of rosparm tal like $(param tal) into argument tal_arg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The solution you linked to involves making a simple python node which reads the desired parameter value and prints it to stdout. You can then use the value="{eval scriptname.py}" syntax to run that node and put the value it outputs into the argument.

Hope this helps

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tal](https://answers.ros.org/users/11486/tal/) on 2018-12-06**:
where i can put this python scrip?
There is other way besides the ways in the link?

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-12-06**:
Ideally it should be inside a catkin package in the src directory. If you don't already have a workspace with a package setup then I recommend having a look at the tutorials to set one up and create a simple node.

**Comment by [just_a_normal_college_student](https://answers.ros.org/users/55039/just_a_normal_college_student/) on 2022-08-04**:
Warning: The mentioned solution DOES NOT work! I tried to implement a python script as recommended, but the "eval" command is not able to interprete it. A more thorough explanation is given here: https://answers.ros.org/question/361411/running-a-python-node-using-eval-in-roslaunch/. As far as I know, there is currently no way to get params into args. An extension to add the "command" attribute to the arg tag is mentioned here: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/723, but not yet implemented as of today.